# double integrals on quantum calculus

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, q-series, quantum-calculus

I need references or book recommendations to find properties of double integrals on quantum calculus. Especially i need analogue of Fubini's theorem on q-calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Professor A. E. Hamza and me published the article for power quantum difference operator which name is "Leibniz’s Rule and Fubini’s Theorem Associated with Power Quantum Diﬀerence Operators". This operator generalizes $q$-diﬀerence operator and yields $q$-difference operator when $n=1$.